# interactively prompt for a list (or regex) rather than just a single item

Tags: buffers, completion, interactive, kill-buffer, iteration

I have a function to kill buffers matching a given regex:

```
;; Like kill-matching-buffers, but doesn't prompt every time.
;; TODO: get this to use vertico
(defun kill-matching-buffers-just-do-it ()
  "Kill buffers whose names match REGEXP, without asking."
  (interactive)
  ;; Replaces "kill-buffer-ask" with 'kill-buffer' using a `let` variant.
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'kill-buffer-ask) #'kill-buffer))
    (call-interactively #'kill-matching-buffers)))
```

It's clear that this function would be way easier to use if it used completion to match the prompt against the list of buffers rather than just prompting for the regex without any feedback.

So, what I want to do is write a function that works like `(interactive "bEnter a buffer:")`, except it returns the list of buffers matching the regex that the user provided (or even just the regex itself) rather than just a single buffer. This seems like it should be possible but I can't figure out how.

Comment: The code and your description make no sense (to me). *What `REGEXP`?*

Comment: The `REGEXP` that I'm referring to is the one that it prompts for when you run the function.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I am using orderless and vertico, so the prompt is a regex by default.

Answer (score 1):

Prompt for the regexp once.

With non-`nil` value of `lexical-binding`:

```lisp
(defun kill-matching-buffers-just-do-it (regexp)
  "Kill buffers whose names match REGEXP, without asking."
  (interactive (list (read-regexp "Regexp: ")))
  (dolist (buf (cl-remove-if-not
                 (lambda (b) (string-match-p regexp (buffer-name b)))
                 (buffer-list)))
    (kill-buffer buf)))
```

With `nil` value of `lexical-binding` (so works in all Emacs versions):

```lisp
(defun kill-matching-buffers-just-do-it (regexp)
  "Kill buffers whose names match REGEXP, without asking."
  (interactive (list (read-regexp "Regexp: ")))
  (dolist (buf (cl-remove-if-not
                 `(lambda (b) (string-match-p ',regexp (buffer-name b)))
                 (buffer-list)))
    (kill-buffer buf)))
```

---

On the other hand, why not just use `kill-matching-buffers` with a non-`nil` `NO-ASK` argument?

> `kill-matching-buffers` is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> `files.el`.
>
> `(kill-matching-buffers REGEXP &optional INTERNAL-TOO NO-ASK)`
>
> Kill buffers whose name matches the specified `REGEXP`.
>
> Ignores buffers whose name starts with a space, unless optional
> prefix argument `INTERNAL-TOO` is non-`nil`.  Asks before killing
> each buffer, unless `NO-ASK` is non-`nil`.

```lisp
(defun kill-matching-buffers-just-do-it (regexp)
  "Kill buffers whose names match REGEXP, without asking."
  (interactive (list (read-regexp "Regexp: ")))
  (kill-matching-buffers regexp nil :NO-ASK))
```

Comment: Using `:NO-ASK` is indeed a much better way to implement `kill-matching-buffers-just-do-it`, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Namely, the problem I'm trying to solve is that `read-regexp` does not provide completion in the same way as `C-x b`.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is replicate the behavior of the `b` code character for `interactive`, except it returns the actual text in the minibuffer rather than a singular match.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a method of doing this:

```
;; Like kill-matching-buffers, but doesn't prompt every time,
;; and it uses orderless with completion
(defun kill-buffers-by-regex ()
  "Kill buffers whose names match REGEXP, without asking."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((buffers (buffer-list))
         (buffnames (mapcar (lambda (x) (buffer-name x)) buffers))
         (input (completing-read "Kill buffers matching: " buffnames nil nil))
         (to-kill (orderless-filter input buffnames)))
    (message (format "%s" to-kill))
    (mapc #'kill-buffer to-kill)))
```